# How to remove the properties in excelsheet?

Tags: php, excel, drupal, phpexcel

I am trying to export drupal views to excel and I am using PHPExcel for creating the excel file. The code is as follows

```
  public static function ExportExcel() {
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once 'libraries/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'libraries/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
               ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
               ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
               ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
               ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
               ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
               ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Add some data
//$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue('TEST PHPEXCEL');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="02simple.xls"');

$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
}
```

The sample data('TEST PHPEXCEl') is also coming up with special characters and sheet properties too.

What can be done to solve this? [image: The output excel sheet looks like this]

Meanwhile I am using Ubuntu for development.

Comment: Why are you not using data export module for this: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export

Comment: The problem is that something is corrupting the file, some output somewhere, perhaps a space or newline character that you're injecting into the output stream

Comment: @MarkBaker. Yes. The problem was with output buffering. Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @MilanG. I am developing a custom export module for my website

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to omit the properties from the sheet and format it.

```
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I think one line code solved my problem

```
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

`header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel')`

to

`header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8')`

Comment: No. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 public static function ExportExcel() {
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="02simple.xls"');


/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once 'libraries/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'libraries/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
               ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
               ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
               ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
               ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
               ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
               ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Add some data
//$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue('TEST PHPEXCEL');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
}
```

Comment: try to create a CSV instead of xls file and see if issue still exist

Comment: @Fky. I added a line of code which solved my problem. I have posted the answer above. Thanks!

Comment: @camel_case. Solved without using CSV. Thank you for the help!